# Count the number of time a certain value appears in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have an api response which I've parsed into Javascript object which looks like this:

```
teams [{
    0:
    1:
    2:
    3:
    4:
    5:
}]
```

Inside each of the 100 numbers contains information as follows:

```
teams [{
    0:
      team_name: "name"
      date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z"
      score: 5
      winning_id: 54
    1:
      team_name: "name"
      date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z"
      score: 5
      winning_id: 24
    2:
      team_name: "name"
      date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z"
      score: 3
      winning_id: 54
    3:
      team_name: "name"
      date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z"
      score: 2
      winning_id: 27
    4:
      team_name: "name"
      date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z"
      score: 4
      winning_id: 75
    5:
      team_name: "name"
      date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z"
      score: 6
      winning_id: 27
}]
```

I need to find and count how many times each different team won using the winning_id. Can anyone help.

I've tried joining all the winning_ids into one array so I can count but that didn't work, I've also tried turning them into strings to count that way but also didn't work.

The results should be a count for each id for example:

54: 2

24: 1

27: 2

75: 1

Comment: could you post valid data structure instead of that pseudo stuff - note: you'd use array reduce function probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const teams = [{
    0: {team_name: "name", date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z", score: 5, winning_id: 54,},
    1: {team_name: "name", date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z", score: 5, winning_id: 24,},
    2: {team_name: "name", date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z", score: 3, winning_id: 54,},
    3: {team_name: "name", date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z", score: 2, winning_id: 27,},
    4: {team_name: "name", date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z", score: 4, winning_id: 75,},
    5: {team_name: "name", date: "2018-06-30T16:02:10Z", score: 6, winning_id: 27,},
}];

const response = Object.values(teams[0]).reduce(
  (res, {winning_id}) => ({
    ...res, 
    [winning_id]: (res[winning_id] || 0) + 1
  }),
{});
console.log(response);
```

You can try Array.reduce() and accumulate on winning_id occurrence